# Call WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection from Console gives Assembly not found error

Tags: .net, console-application

I've been at this for awhile and can't seem to get by this.  I have a console application that needs to call `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()`.  I worked through a few issues already but now I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have run from the PackageManager both Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers and Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core.

I have verified the assembly referenced version of System.Web.Providers is 2.0.0.0 and CopyToLocal is set to true.

I have verified the assembly is present in the bin directory.

This is my App.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider"
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider"
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
             connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, wrecked my head all morning getting resolved. I knew what the problem was but I could not find System.Web.Providers 2.0.0.0 I could only find version 1.

Many resources I found online suggested that I try the following commands through NuGet package manager console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core
```

However these kept installing version 1.0.0.0 and I like yourself needed 2.0.0

The way in which I resolved it was to go to

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution

When the dialog came up, I went to the update section and looked for the Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers Core Libraries and hit update.

[image]

When I run the commands through the console it was always installing version 1 when I went this way it added version 2.

Hopefully this helps, if you have since solved it hopefully it helps someone else like myself who spent the morning searching for a solution.